# jquery - how to get nth-child number value from list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a number value from a list into jQuery.  The list in the html looks like

```
    <ul class="score">
      <li id="str">8</li>
      <li id="dex">9</li>
      <li id="con">10</li>
    </ul>
```

I use jQuery to figure out which value the user is clicking by doing this:

```
    $("ul.score li").click(function(){
      var index = $(this).index();
```

Which gives the index.  Finally, this is where I am stuck, I want to get the value of the score so I can do calculations.  I want to use nth-child as I have the index.  This is what I did (doesn't work):

```
    var abilityScore = $("ul.score li:nth-child(index)").html();
```

How do I get this to work?  Please help!!

Answer (score 3):

Why even bother with the index, use `$(this).html()`

```
$("ul.score li").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).html();
});
```

Comment: yeah I see what you mean.  Actually it was referring to a list (I use that list as increase buttons, another list for decrease buttons), but I was simplifying things here.  Valid point though.

Answer (score 2):

As `this` already points to `li`, Simply use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$("ul.score li").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).text(); //You can also use .html()
});
```

Whenever you need to use variable in selector. Use string concatenation, here is an example:

```
$("ul.score li:nth-child(" + index +")").html()
```

Comment: thanks!  Concatenation is what I was looking for.